# unable to install mailspring on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation, deb, email-client

Total newbie to Linux here,

So i just downloaded `mailspring-1.0.7-amd64.deb`

and i tried to install via Software install but nothing happens,

So i tried to install via terminal `sudo dpkg -i mailspring-1.0.7-amd64.deb`

It gave following error:

```
Selecting previously unselected package mailspring.
(Reading database ... 329215 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mailspring-1.0.7-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mailspring (1.0.7) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mailspring:
 mailspring depends on libsecret-1-dev; however:
  Package libsecret-1-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mailspring (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mailspring
```

I also did **`sudo apt-get install -f`**

It gave following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mailspring
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 280 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 329463 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mailspring (1.0.7) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
```

And I am still unable to install it please help

Comment: Try `sudo apt install ./mailspring-1.0.7-amd64.deb`?

Comment: Have you tried installing libsecret-1-dev?

Comment: it has cascading dependendencies like libglib2.0-dev requires zlib1g-dev

Answer (score 2):

First install the missing package:

 `sudo apt install libsecret-1-dev`

then install the package by running:

`sudo dpkg -i mailspring-1.0.7-amd64.deb`

Before you install any package via dpkg, you should run:

`sudo dpkg -I <package>`

to get the list of dependencies the package requires and installing them beforehand.

Comment: You can also use `sudo gdebi <package_name>` - it's safer than `dpkg -i <package_name>` because if dependencies don't check Ok, it won't try to install.